# How to send photo using Facebook app from another android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I am using the below code. It opens the Facebook Messenger app, but the image is not shown (with broken image symbol) and sending fails.

```
List<Bitmap> abc = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
abc.add(pic);
FacebookDialog.PhotoMessageDialogBuilder builder = new FacebookDialog.PhotoMessageDialogBuilder(LocationShare.this);
builder.addPhotos(abc);
builder.build().present();
```

is there any problem in the way i add photos? i mean using List
i have mentioned content provider in android manifest.xml
i am able send link using below code.

FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder = new     FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(getActivity())
    .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/")
    .setName("Message Dialog Tutorial")
    .setCaption("Build great social apps that engage your friends.")
    .setPicture("https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiRtu.png")
    .setDescription("Allow your users to message links from your app using the Android SDK.");

Comment: take a look at[FacebookImageShareIntent](https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent)

Answer (score 2):

Did you add a content provider?

If you look at the javadocs for addPhotos (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookDialog.PhotoMessageDialogBuilder/#addPhotos) it says that a NativeAppCallContentProvider must be specified in your AndroidManifest.

In the docs for NativeAppCallContentProvider (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/NativeAppCallContentProvider/) it tells you how to add the content provider.

You can also have a look in the HelloFacebook sample which has an example of adding the content provider in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: yes. i am using content provider. i am able to send links also. problem is only for photos. i suspect the way i am adding photos, using List<Bitmap>. facebook reference says, argument to addPhotos is a collection.  public PhotoDialogBuilderBase addPhotos(Collection photos)

Comment: Using a list is fine. Can you edit your question to show how you're using the content provider?